# Xamarin & IIS LocalHost WebApi gives error - System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Network subsystem is down'

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api2

I have 2 Applications here. One is a Xamarin Application and the other is a Asp.Net MVC Application which has the WebApi to connect to a SqlServer Database "where the database is on a Hosted Website of like some IP Address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" .

I run the MVC application Locally to IIS, and then Once the Website is Up in IIS, I run the Xamarin Application from the second instance of Visual Studio.

Firstly I don't think the MVC WebApi gets called, because I tried putting Breakpoints there and it does not come there. I don't know why. Because I had done the same thing with a Winforms and MVC application (WebApi), then at least the WebApi was getting called which I saw with breakpoints in the MVC application.

Now in Xamarin I am getting this error

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Network subsystem is down'
```

in the line

```
var responseTask = await client.GetAsync("ConnectToAscDatabase");
```

I have this code in Xamarin Application's MainPage.cs

```
        private async void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49252/api/");

                // !!! This Line gives the error System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Network subsystem is down'
                var responseTask = await client.GetAsync("ConnectToAscDatabase");

                var readTask = responseTask.Content.ReadAsAsync<Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection>();
                SqlConnection con = readTask.Result;
                var staty = con.State;
            }
        }
```

and this is a WebApi

```
        public class ConnectToAscDatabaseController : ApiController
        {
            public async Task<Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection> Get()
            {
                string SqlServer_ServerPath_Server = "SomeServer";
                string SqlServer_Database_Server = "SomeDatabase";
                string SqlServer_User_Server = "SomeUser";
                string SqlServer_Password_Server = "SomePassword";
                int timeOutInSeconds = 15;
                string connectionString = "data source=" + SqlServer_ServerPath_Server + ";" + "initial catalog=" + SqlServer_Database_Server + ";" + "user id=" + SqlServer_User_Server + ";" + "Password=" + SqlServer_Password_Server + ";" + "Trusted_Connection=false" + ";" + "Connection Timeout=" + timeOutInSeconds + ";" + "Persist Security Info=False";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                return con;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you using android emulator?

Comment: do NOT use localhost.  Use the IP of your server.  And be sure that your local IIS is configured to allow external connections

Comment: Yes i am using Android Emulator

Comment: "localhost" will tell the Android emulator to connect back to **itself**, not to your local server.  That's why you should use the IP.

Comment: Jason I tried using my Live Website URL client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com/api/"); and I do not get the error, but the connection object returned has all the ConnectionString, State and ALL the Properties as NULL (more specifically it says 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object' againts all the values in the Connection object.

Comment: sorry about me deleting my other comments. I thought they must not be proper as i was not getting any answer.

Comment: Your WebAPI should NOT return an SQL Connection to your client (that will never work).  Your WebAPI should execute queries on behalf of your client and return data objects.

Comment: Jason I have .Net Standard Library project which have methods which I am using by referencing these libraries in my Winforms application. Now I want to use the same methods for my Xamarin Application. I thought I can reference the same .Net Standard Library project in my Xamarin application, and I can just pass the SqlConnection from my Xamarin Application to those .Net Standard Methods which take a SqlConnection (just like I am passing SqlConnection from Winforms project to these .Net Standard project Methods). Winforms app Uses the SqlServer database which is on a hosted Web Server.

Comment: Your WebAPI project should use the .Net Standard library, and expose endpoints which your Xamarin apps should connect to.  Your Xamarin apps should not connect directly to your SQL server, that is incredibly insecure.

Comment: I mean is that what you mean by EndPoints.

Comment: Yes.  There are hundreds of articles and tutorials on writing webservices that you can refer to

Comment: Thanx a ton jason. One more thing, suppose my winforms application uses local machine instance of sqlserver for one setting of the winforms application, and connects to hosted database for other settings, then my webapi and .Net standard projects on the webserver will not be able to do that.

Comment: Also for each application project of mine, i may need to host seperate webapi projects. Each webapi for each application.

Comment: Also wont debugging the  project be tough because SqlConnection will only work on a live hosted webapi. So everytime you make a change in the .Net standard and webapi code, we need to upload it and then...

Comment: @BeeGees, About  displaying data using mvc api in Xamarin.forms, there are many article you can take a look:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fetch-data-from-web-api-using-xamarin-forms/,more detailed info about using mvc api to get data, you can take a look:https://medium.com/better-programming/building-a-restful-api-with-asp-net-web-api-and-sql-server-ce7873d5b331

Comment: @BeeGees, I find my first link have some issue, so I give one reply for correct and detailed info, if my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

From this documentation, [Android's Network Address Space](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses) is responsible as there is no direct connection from the emulator to your local machine, except with the IP Address "10.0.2.2". You can attach your port number to target whatever services you are trying to reach.

It is also worth noting that for service running with self-signed certificates, you still may not get a connection because of trust issues as Android and IOS will not honor connections to services running with self-signed certificates. [Read more from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services#bypass-the-certificate-security-check).

I use the following codes to resolve those issues (On Android):

Shared Project (Add the following interface):

```
using System.Net.Http;

namespace DemoApp.Services
{
    public interface IHttpClientHandlerService
    {
        HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler();
    }
}
```

Android Project (Add the following class):

```
using DemoApp.Droid.Services;
using DemoApp.Services;
using System.Net.Http;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(HttpClientHandlerService))]
namespace DemoApp.Droid.Services
{
    public class HttpClientHandlerService : IHttpClientHandlerService
    {
        public HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler()
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
                {
                    if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
                        return true;
                    return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
                }
            };
            return handler;
        }
    }
}
```

Now from within your codes you can create a new HttpClient using the following:

```
#if DEBUG
    HttpClientHandler insecureHandler = DependencyService.Get<IHttpClientHandlerService>().GetInsecureHandler();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(insecureHandler);
#else
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
#endif
```

Note: There are better ways of creating an HttpClient (like using dependency injection and IHttpClientFactory) and it is up to the reader to use what suites them best.

For the BaseAddress of HttpClient, you can use the following code as well:

```
public static string BaseAddress =
    DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "http://10.0.2.2:5000" : "http://localhost:5000";
public static string TodoItemsUrl = $"{BaseAddress}/api/todoitems/";
```

where port 5000 may be the port to reach your service and todoitems may be the api url to invoke.

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
I managed to get the same information from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction but you comment was very easy to follow.
Unfortunately I didn't get the emulator working with https -connection even with this solution so eventually I decided to just use http in development and leave the https to live version.

Answer (score -6):

According to your description, you want to display data using web api in Xamarin.Forms, there are many article about this, you can take a look:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fetch-data-from-web-api-using-xamarin-forms/

You need to make sure the Web API project is up and running because the Xamarin app will call WebAPI to access data.

More detailed info about building an ASP.NET Web API with Entity Framework and retrieve data from an SQL server, you can also take a look:

https://medium.com/better-programming/building-a-restful-api-with-asp-net-web-api-and-sql-server-ce7873d5b331